# The present perfect or the past simple

Tags: tense

I think that both are correct, but what's the difference?

It hasn't happened yet. It's all in the future.

> Before you find out what **happened** I'll have known about it for a
> few hours.
>
> Before you find out what **has happened** I'll have known about it
> for a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

The second implies that the 'happening' was very recent, or is expected to happen soon. British English speakers use the present perfect in this way more often than Americans.

Comment: But it hasn't happened. It's all in the future.

Comment: Both sentences could be understood to refer to a past incident that neither person knows the details of yet, or something that is expected to happen in the near future.